# How can I make a 240 volt 4 wire to 3 wire extension/adapter cord?

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v

I have an existing 240 outlet wired into the wall of my shop. It's there to run a phase converter that I use about 2 hours a week. I want to use this circuit to run a 240 window air conditioner when the phase converter is off.

The air conditioner arrived today and has only 3 conductors on the power cord. I looked up the configuration and determined that it's a 240v 15 amp set up.

I want to make a short extension cord, about 6 ft, to connect the 3 conductor plug from the AC to the 4 conductor 240v wall receptacle. The wall side would be an 4 conductor plug that fits the receptacle. The AC side would be a 3 conductor receptacle that fits the end of the AC power cord. So my extension cord would only be 3 conductor (no ground) going into the 4 conductor wall receptacle.

I've spent enough time around electricians to know how to connect wires and such safely. Just not sure if omitting the ground will work. The manufacturer of the AC apparently thinks so or they would not have made it with only 3 conductors.

Comment: What type of plug is on the A/C unit cord? Is it a NEMA 6 (hot, hot, ground) or a NEMA 10 (hot, hot, neutral)? (If you can't tell, here's a [pictorial guide](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/NEMA_simplified_pins.svg/765px-NEMA_simplified_pins.svg.png)).

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel beat me to it-- your AC could have a ground with two conductors.

Comment: There is NO way a new A/C would have a NEMA 10 plug on it. They were only older ranges and dryers. This unit will have a 6-15P plug on it. If you were to make a cord you'd be omitting the neutral, NOT the ground.

Comment: Note that the chart @ThreePhaseEel posted shows the *receptacle* layout—the plug on the *appliance* will have the opposite configuration.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey -- not sure if it's a brand-new or a used AC, but I agree that it's most likely a 6-15.

Comment: Could you please include the make, model, and/or photo of the nameplate of the equipment you're trying to power.

Comment: Read the manufacturer's documentation for the A/C unit, as it may specifically mention not using an extension cord.

Comment: @Tester101 -- what he wants is rather equal parts "adapter" and "extension cord" -- also, would it be possible to fabricate an extension cord so that it could be used with a window A/C safely? (the manual basically says "don't use this with a garden-variety extension cord because they have sucky voltage drop when the A/C starts up and pulls inrush current", but I suspect that some 10-2 W/G SOOW or similarly beefy wire would deal with *that* issue rather nicely...)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Depending on the setup, the extension cord could (and likely would) be being used in place of permanent wiring. Which is a code violation. The proper way to handle this, is to install a new circuit (with proper receptacle), or extend the existing circuit following all applicable codes (including using a proper receptacle).

Comment: @Tester101 -- true -- some 12/2 W/G NM in surface raceway might be a better bet than a cord, even

Comment: ThreePhaseEel: The plug type is  NEMA 6-15.

Comment: Tester101: Here's a link to a .pdf spec sheet   http://c.shld.net/assets/docs/spin_prod_786786512.pdf

Comment: Tester nailed it. I want to extend the power cord a few feet and deal with the plug configuration issue at the same time, if possible, rather than run a new circuit, etc. I assumed a beefy wire would take care of any voltage drop issues. But...I'm no pro...that's why I'm here looking for help. Appreciate all the comments and suggestions!

Comment: Just to be clear...not planning on cutting into the power cord or anything. Rather, was imagining I'd use surface raceway with a surface receptacle box for the AC unit and an appropriate 4 prong plug for the existing hot outlet...if that makes sense.

Comment: What type of receptacle is the existing receptacle (NEMA configuration)?

Comment: Existing receptacle is NEMA 10-50.

Answer (score 3):

To do this properly, You'll likely have to run a new circuit.  Since you haven't posted the make, model, or nameplates of the equipment, it's impossible to say for sure if these two devices can be on the same circuit. If they can, the solution is to extend the circuit using approved methods and materials. If they can't, the solution is to run a new circuit.

As for making an extension cord, that's not the best option.  Extension cords are for temporary use only, and should not be used in place of permanent wiring.

---

## **WARNING:**

### Using an extension/adapter cord like this is dangerous, and can lead to loss of property and/or life. This is a theoretical device, that should never exist.  **DO NOT** make, use, or even think about a device like this.

> If you're dead set on making and extension/adapter, you'll want to use proper sized conductors and protect the cable from physical damage.
>
>  Since you're plugging it into a 50 ampere circuit, you'll have to size the conductors to be able to carry 50 amperes. This is not typically the way it's done, but this is not a typical solution.  If the A/C overloads, you don't want the cord bursting into flames. So since the overcurrent device is set to 50 amperes, you'll have to have appropriately sized conductors.
>
>  A safer option would be to build a smaller overcurrent device in to the adapter, to protect the cord and A/C unit. In this case you'd have 50 ampere conductors attached to a NEMA 14-50 plug, with the other end of the conductors connected to some form of 30 ampere overcurrent protection. Then from the 30 ampere overcurrent protection, you'd run 30 ampere conductors to a NEMA 6-15 receptacle. Then you could plug the A/C into the 6-15 receptacle.

## **WARNING:**

### Using an extension/adapter cord like this is dangerous, and can lead to loss of property and/or life. This is a theoretical device, that should never exist.  **DO NOT** make, use, or even think about a device like this.

The safest option would be to install a new panel, and have it being fed by the conductors that are currently feeding the 14-50 receptacle.  Then you can branch to each of the devices from the panel, using proper methods and materials.

Comment: [AC information provided in comment on question](http://c.shld.net/assets/docs/spin_prod_786786512.pdf)

Comment: Info on the phase converter, and the existing receptacle are still required.

Comment: The phase converter and the AC unit would not be in use simultaneously...there is not enough head room left on the service panel...hence my desire for plugs. I had hoped I could create an extension cord that would have NEMA 10-50 on one end for the hot receptacle (but with no neutral connected) and NEMA 6-15 on the other for the AC unit.

Comment: From the manual: "American  Rotary  rotary  phase  converters  can  run  any  type  of  load,  resistive, inductive, multiple motor, and in any combination and or number."  Here's a link to the .pdf for the phase converter in case it helps. I have the 20 hp model.

Comment: @Jim NEMA 10-50 is a three prong receptacle (hot, hot, neutral).  I thought you said it was a four prong receptacle

Comment: Also note that just because you *say* you're not going to run the equipment simultaneously, is not the same as installing it in such a way as to prevent it.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, it's your house.  I'm just telling you that what you want to do is not the proper way to do it.

Comment: Tester: my mistake...receptacle is NEMA 14-50. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ...and very much appreciate all your input. I want to be sure to do this safely!

Comment: @Jim, since you already mentioned using a "surface raceway with a surface receptacle box," installing a small panel does not complicate things much more than what you're already planning on doing. You're just looking at a few relatively inexpensive extra parts and a _smidge_ more work. Go with Tester101's advice-- it will be worth your safety & peace of mind.

Comment: @Tester101 -- interestingly enough, since a NEMA 14-50 is a single (not a duplex) receptacle -- the cord and plug approach *does* meet the requirement of "you can't use both the phase converter and the A/C at the same time".

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel True enough. But it's still not the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for the thoughtful replies...so many details and facets to the situation that I would never have known about.

Comment: Seems like the safe way to go is to install a subpanel and wire a dedicated circuit for the air conditioner. It's more work than I was hoping for, but really don't want to cut corners with safety.

Comment: The panel that feeds the shop area, where my equipment is, and where I want to install the AC unit, is itself a sub panel fed from my house panel. Is it okay to have a sub panel fed from another sub panel?

Comment: @Jim No problem having a panel feed a panel that feeds a panel, as long as they're all installed properly. Just remember not to bond ground and "neutral" together in the panel.

Comment: Great...I think that's the way to go. I can find more detailed "how to" info from here. Thanks again for the advice and input!